# How do I display Html file using Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, frontend, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to display the local Html file on the form which I created. The code that I've written is [TargetHTMLCODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CiGx.png) and that code should be display on this webpage form [WebPage Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViwB5.png) . Can you tell me what am doing wrong? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Don't show images of code around here.  We want the text version of it.

Comment: Sorry about it, next time I'll do it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to make a new instance of webBrowser1. Just put it in form and in `Load` event of form navigate to your HTML.

```
  public Form1()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
       Load += Form1_Load;
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(@"file:///C:/test.html"));
  }
```

[image]